# Nvidia settings not saved after reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

Running ubuntu 15.04.  My nvidia settings are not saved.  I run dual screens and they keeps switching after a reboot. I ran the nvidia settings using sudo

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

and made sure to save to xorg file.  But it is not saving.   This is the file after the update.

xorg file:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 346.59  (buildd@toyol)  Thu Apr  9 09:44:23 UTC 2015

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Impression *22W1*"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 630"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +1680+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Where do you save this file to?

Comment: Easy answer: physically switch the two screens :P

Comment: The file is saved at /etc/x11/xorg.conf    Switching the screens is not an option at the moment.  There are two outputs on the card.  VGA and HDMI.    The screens are different models and only fit the vga or hdmi.   Unfortunately it appears that the HDMI is considered port1 which is what Im assuming its defaulting to on bootup.  But the VGA is a larger screen and my main one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could edit the xorg.conf file like mentioned below.
I do not have an exact same configuration but have some experience with Nvidia and X Server settings. I don't know if you need to do both steps but perhaps you will need to.

After each change to xorg.conf file you can test the new settings with

> restart lightdm

without the need to reboot the computer.
Please make a backup copy of your current xorg.conf file in case something goes wrong and you need to revert to previous working settings.

You can try to edit these two lines *"nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder"* and *"metamodes"*.

1.According to [Nvidia](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/325.15/README/xconfigoptions.html) the *"nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder"* lists/orders the attached devices according to certain rules. Perhaps you should set "DFP" as the first device instead of "CRT". You'll have to do this in a text editor.

2.The other thing is "metamodes". If you play with

> nvidia-settings

(as root user) and switch both screens in the X server Display Configuration. So once VGA is on the left and HDMI on the right and then the other way around (VGA on the right and HDMI on the left) and save the xorg.conf each time to see the difference. Assuming you have a horizontal configuration of course but it is the same if you have a vertical configuration. You should see a difference in the position parameter (your current says *VGA-0:... +0+0, DVI-I-0... +1680+0)*. This way you can (manually) set the position of the screens.

In your case if you wanted to exchange VGA and HDMI you shoudl have something like this *DVI-I-0... +0+0, VGA-0:... +xyz+0,)* where *xyz* is the horizontal resolution of your screen on HDMI.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I tried your proposition (changing xorg.conf, rebooting and checking what happened) but it seems that xorg.conf file is ignored. I replaced position of DVI-I-1 and DVI-I-2 but it doesn't have any impact. My screens are in wrong order. Maybe do you know why? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: 1. Are you sure the xorg.conf file was saved after you edited it? 2. If you change the resolution or the refresh rate (or turn one screen completely off) in the xorg.conf is that reflected on your screen? This way you at least know that the xorg.conf you are editing is functional.

Comment: eMKi: I realised that xorg.conf is properly run, but during boot, after fraction of seconds screen goes blank and loads again (with added wallpaper) and is messed up. I realised, that after applying xorg.conf, there is another *thing* that changes those settings. Then I tried to change screen order in Ubuntu Display's settings windows and it worked. Those settings in xorg.conf are useless because Ubuntu windows manager doesn't use them. This is stupid!

Comment: Intersting. I use Xubuntu 14.04 so I was not aware of this situation. It is good to know though. Thank you for your input.